# why this json string does not print after decoding

Tags: php, json

i have json like this,

```
[{
    "element": "<div class="
    fb - autocomplete form - group field - autocomplete - 1482728916013 - preview "><label for="
    autocomplete - 1482728916013 - preview " class="
    fb - autocomplete - label ">Autocomplete  </label> <input type="
    autocomplete " class="
    autocomplete " name="
    autocomplete - 1482728916013 - preview " id="
    autocomplete - 1482728916013 - preview "></div>"
}, {
    "element": "<div class="
    fb - button form - group field - button - 1482728916826 - preview "><button type="
    button " class="
    button - input btn -
    default btn " name="
    button - 1482728916826 - preview " style="
    default " id="
    button - 1482728916826 - preview ">Button</button></div>"
}, {
    "element": "<div class="
    fb - checkbox form - group field - checkbox - 1482728917611 - preview "><input type="
    checkbox " class="
    checkbox " name="
    checkbox - 1482728917611 - preview " id="
    checkbox - 1482728917611 - preview "> <label for="
    checkbox - 1482728917611 - preview " class="
    fb - checkbox - label ">Checkbox  </label></div>"
}, {
    "element": "<div class="
    fb - date form - group field - date - 1482728918827 - preview "><label for="
    date - 1482728918827 - preview " class="
    fb - date - label ">Date Field  </label> <input type="
    date " class="
    calendar " name="
    date - 1482728918827 - preview " id="
    date - 1482728918827 - preview "></div>"
}]
```

after encoding array i saved it to the database like

```
$element = json_encode($element_array);  // next i saved it to the database
```

my `json` (i,e `$element`) is like the above `json`.  What is the error in this `json`?

here is my demo which prints nothing why? DEMO : http://phpio.net/s/2bsw

QUESTION: after `encoding` i saved json into database but i'm not getting any output it,seems that this json is not a valid despite `json_encoding()`. WHY?

what is the best way to encode json before storing it into the database

Comment: your json data is not correct. Please check here:- http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: json is not valid

Comment: @Anant,i'm `encoding` it then `saving` into `database` then why this `json`  is `invalid`???

Comment: JSON can't have newlines in strings, they should be encoded as `\n`, and if you have double quotes inside a string they have to be escaped with backslash. What you've shown isn't the result of calling `json_encode()`.

Comment: JSON would look like `"<div class=\"\n     fb - date form - group field - date - 1482728918827 - preview \"><label for=\"`

Comment: Use jsonlint.com to validate your JSON.

Comment: @Barmar, what `json` i have showed is a `result` of `json_encode` which is a single line `string` after using `jsolint` it made into `new line`.  my question is `how` to `encode` an `array` properly into `json` format?

Answer (score 2):

I looked into your demo link you provided : http://phpio.net/s/2bsw and your JSON string has concatenation problem. It should be something like the following and then it will print the array result:

```
$ele = '[{"element":"<div class=\'fb-autocomplete form-group field-autocomplete-1482728916013-preview\'><label for=\'autocomplete-1482728916013-preview\' class=\'fb-autocomplete-label\'>Autocomplete  </label> <input type=\'autocomplete\' class=\'autocomplete\' name=\'autocomplete-1482728916013-preview\' id=\'autocomplete-1482728916013-preview\'></div>"},{"element":"<div class=\'fb-button form-group field-button-1482728916826-preview\'><button type=\'button\' class=\'button-input btn-default btn\' name=\'button-1482728916826-preview\' style=\'default\' id=\'button-1482728916826-preview\'>Button</button></div>"},{"element":"<div class=\'fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-1482728917611-preview\'><input type=\'checkbox\' class=\'checkbox\' name=\'checkbox-1482728917611-preview\' id=\'checkbox-1482728917611-preview\'> <label for=\'checkbox-1482728917611-preview\' class=\'fb-checkbox-label\'>Checkbox  </label></div>"},{"element":"<div class=\'fb-date form-group field-date-1482728918827-preview\'><label for=\'date-1482728918827-preview\' class=\'fb-date-label\'>Date Field  </label> <input type=\'date\' class=\'calendar\' name=\'date-1482728918827-preview\' id=\'date-1482728918827-preview\'></div>"}]';
```

For more information on concatenation of quoted strings, refer the following link:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Hope this helps